# How to get the page source of a webpage using jersey client in java

Tags: java, jersey-client

In my web application using java, I am trying to get the page source of a web page using jersey client by passing the URL of the required page. I have been searching the web to find some good examples that would help me, but couldn't find any.
Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: jersey is for web services. But in general, you can get the HTML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey is for web services. But in general, you can get the HTML source. 
All these 4 varieties of jax-rs clients will print you the code:

1. URLConnection client

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
       import java.net.URL;
       import java.net.URLConnection;
       public class URLConnectionClient {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       URL restURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/resources/myresource/usernamepwdcontext");
       URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) restURL.openConnection();
       connection.setDoOutput(true);
       connection.connect();
       InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(ins);
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(inputLine);
       }
       in.close();
       }
       }
2. HttpConnection client

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.URL;
   public class HttpConnectionClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   URL restURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/resources/myresource/usernamepwdcontext");
   HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) restURL.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
   connection.connect();
   InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(ins);
   String inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine())!=null) {
   System.out.println(inputLine);
   }

   }
   }
3. URL stream client

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.URL;
   public class URLOpenClient {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   URL restURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/resources/myresource/usernamepwdcontext");
   InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(restURL.openStream());
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(ins);
   String inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(inputLine);
   }
   in.close();
   }
   }
4. Jersey client.

   import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
   import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
   import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
   import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
   public class URLJerseyClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
   WebTarget target = cl.target("http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/resources/myresource/usernamepwdcontext");
   target.path("resource");
   Builder requestBuilder = target.request();
   Response response = requestBuilder.get();
   System.out.println(response.getStatus());
   System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
   }
   }

For this one you will need a dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.vvirlan</groupId>
<artifactId>cert</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Client</name>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

[4 JAX-RS clients](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/jax-rs-4-ways-to-implement-a-client-for-web-services/)

Comment: thanks for the details and all of these worked except the last one where the 'response.readEntity(String.class)' showed an error for me, could you please update it to return a string that contain the entire page source. I am also having an issue that some symbols like '&nbsp', '-', single quote etc are displayed as '?'...Have you got any solution for that....thanks in advance

Comment: The strange symbols are due to UTF / other encoding problems. Search for how to encode a string

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is just to download html code (not render it) you can do with any normal http client (or even java URLConnection classes)

Below is one ready sample I used in one of my tool. It uses apache http core 4.1.4 and apache http client 4.1.4.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class HttpUtil {

    public static String getFile(String sUrl) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

         // Prepare a request object
         HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sUrl);

         // Execute the request
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

         // Examine the response status
         System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

         // Get hold of the response entity
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

         // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
         // to worry about connection release
         if (entity != null) {
             InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
             try {

                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(instream));
                 // do something useful with the response
                 String s = reader.readLine();
                 while(s!= null){
                     b.append(s);
                     b.append("\n");
                     s = reader.readLine();
                 }
             } catch (IOException ex) {

                 // In case of an IOException the connection will be released
                 // back to the connection manager automatically
                 throw ex;

             } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

                 // In case of an unexpected exception you may want to abort
                 // the HTTP request in order to shut down the underlying
                 // connection and release it back to the connection manager.
                 httpget.abort();
                 throw ex;

             } finally {

                 // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                 instream.close();

             }

             // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
             // shut down the connection manager to ensure
             // immediate deallocation of all system resources
             httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
         }
         return b.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks and it worked. But when I have a code like   '<p>&nbsp</p> '  It is returned as  '<p>�</p>'. Is there a solution for this